# How to wait for a CopyOnWriteArrayList to be empty?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` that's used in 3 Threads:

The first *thread* **fills** the list;

The second *thread* **removes** the Objects from the list;

The third *thread* is triggered when the first thread is interrupted, so no more Objects are added to the list, but are still removed in the second thread.

I want this *thread* to wait for this list to be empty. What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Easiest way to do is by taking a flag variable.

Comment: `while(!list.isEmpty()) {
      Thread.sleep(100);    
 }`

Comment: @diginoise I don't want to use a sleep, I prefer a more... "efficient" way (wait/notify, CountDownLatch etc...)

Comment: Thread 2: `\\consume the entire list; synchronized(list) { list.notifyAll(); }` , Thread 3: `synchronized(list) {while(!list.isEmpty()) {wait();} }`

Comment: When T1 quits, it can set a flag in T2. When T2 completed all the removing, it will check the flag and do T3's job. No need for T3.